# Convert dataframe columns into dict and save it as json file, with columns name as dict key and row values as dict values

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, convertto-json

I have a pandas dataframe as below :

```html
device_id   user_id level
d_id1   u_id1   1
d_id1   u_id2   -1
d_id1   u_id3   1
d_id2   u_id100 -1
d_id3   u_id100 1
d_id3   u_id4   1
```

I want to convert it into a list of dictionaries depend on columns and rows that looks like:

```html
[
{
"device_id":d_id1
"result_key":[
                {"user_id":u_id1,"level":1},
                {"user_id":u_id2,"level":-1},
                {"user_id":u_id3,"level":1}
             ]
},
{
"device_id":d_id2
"result_key":[{"user_id":u_id100,"level":-1}]
},
{
"device_id":d_id3
"result_key":[{"user_id":u_id100,"level":1},
              {"user_id":u_id4,"level":1}
              ]
}
]
```

What is the effecient way to do that and save it into json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for `result_key` column first, then for dictionary use `to_dict` with both columns:

```
d = (df.groupby('device_id')[['user_id','level']].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records'))
       .reset_index(name='result_key')
       .to_dict('records'))
print (d)
[{'device_id': 'd_id1', 'result_key': [{'user_id': 'u_id1', 'level': 1}, 
                                       {'user_id': 'u_id2', 'level': -1}, 
                                       {'user_id': 'u_id3', 'level': 1}]}, 
 {'device_id': 'd_id2', 'result_key': [{'user_id': 'u_id100', 'level': -1}]},
 {'device_id': 'd_id3', 'result_key': [{'user_id': 'u_id100', 'level': 1}, 
                                       {'user_id': 'u_id4', 'level': 1}]}]
```

Last convert dictionary to json file:

```
import json
with open('out.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(d, f)
```